# jquery cycle plugin: there is no loop

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

If i wanted the plugin on this page to move automatically, what should i be adding?

There doesn't seems to be a reference of this option in the jquery cycle help files.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager3.html

Thx,

Why am I getting this message?

All new questions are subjected to a "minimum quality" filter that checks for characteristics of extremely poor questions. Your question has been caught by the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `timeout` param. Set it like

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 2000, 
    pager:  '#nav', 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        // return selector string for existing anchor 
        return '#nav li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
    } 
});
```

It's value is in `milliseconds`. After that time it will change to next image.

Check this options reference page http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: @kevinius, Joy took the time to help you, the very least you could do is come back in ten minutes to accept his answer.

Comment: @kevinius You are most welcome, Glad to be able to help. :)

Comment: @kevinius this site isn't going anywhere lol.. best developer help resource out there. Certain safeguards have to be in place to protect the legitimacy of the content and new users. Be thankful a group of people put together a site where you get free answers and support from literally thousands of developers with more skill than you. No offense but your comments come across as very spoiled/entitled.. having to come back and click a checkmark after ten minutes to a solution from a stranger that may have saved you a few hours of headaches? Seems a fair deal to me.